# Symfony 4 memory leak when clear cache

Tags: php, symfony, memory-leaks, doctrine-orm

I have Symfony app which is built on Symfony 3, but recently I upgraded to Symfony 4. Now I have a problem when clearing cache.
When I run command to clear cache I'm getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in var/cache/dev/ContainerGGUArAR/getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService.php on line 85.

`php.ini memory_limit` is set to -1.

I found that `ServiceEntityRepository` is causing the problem, because when I extend this service to one repository I get this error.

Does somebody know what should I try to fix it?

Just to mention that `memory_limit` is set also for CLI to be unlimited

Comment: Could you post the code for the repository?

Answer (score 3):

It is not the solution to the core of your problem but probably allows you to clear the cache even with very large contents:

Try

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/console cache:clear

or when console is in app/ folder

php -d memory_limit=-1 app/console cache:clear
```

Or

```
rm -rf var/cache

or when cache is in app/ folder

rm -rf app/cache
```

I use "rm" very often instead of the bin/console command. This does not do any cache warmup so the loading of the first page will take longer. Sometimes I get better results clearing cache manually in comparison of the bin/console command...